# Chrome turns cursor to default instead of pointer when hovering links after mouseup event that returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I might be missing something because this thing is plain weird. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });
})
```

```html
<a href="">qagq3gq343</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
```

It just returns false on `mouseup` event. But what it does in Chrome, is that when hovering over links, after an `mouseup` event, the cursor is default and not pointer.

You can replicate it above by running the snippet, then clicking anywhere within the snippet **not** on the link, then moving your cursor over the link.

Any ideas?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see the described behaviour just by clicking somewhere else on the page, including in the snippet you just edited in.  Does indeed appear to be an odd Chrome bug.

Comment: [Reproduced without jQuery too](https://jsfiddle.net/tfq8h9hw/)

Comment: Specifically it's preventing the default that does it (not stopping propagation). (Since jQuery's `return false` does both, thought it best to disambiguate.)

Comment: Catalin, you might consider reporting this as a bug (after searching) [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). A quick search for "cancel mouseup" didn't find anything relevant, but you'll want to do a more thorough search before opening a new issue for it.

Comment: I took the liberty of filing this issue since I was experiencing this as well: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686209

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only solution is a css one:

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```